# How to write to CSV in Spark

Tags: file, csv, hadoop, apache-spark, distributed-computing

I'm trying to find an effective way of saving the result of my Spark Job as a csv file. I'm using Spark with Hadoop and so far all my files are saved as `part-00000`.

Any ideas how to make my spark saving to file with a specified file name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write the resulting RDD to a csv file in Spark python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31898964/how-to-write-the-resulting-rdd-to-a-csv-file-in-spark-python)

Comment: @gsamaras given the timing, that question might a possible duplicate of this one :]

Comment: The content matters to be more, than the timing, but that's fine. You made a great question, that's why I upvoted too! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write single CSV file using spark-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674530/write-single-csv-file-using-spark-csv)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Since Spark uses Hadoop File System API to write data to files, this is sort of inevitable. If you do

```
rdd.saveAsTextFile("foo")
```

It will be saved as "`foo/part-XXXXX`" with one part-* file every partition in the RDD you are trying to save. The reason each partition in the RDD is written a separate file is for fault-tolerance. If the task writing 3rd partition (i.e. to `part-00002`) fails, Spark simply re-run the task and overwrite the partially written/corrupted `part-00002`, with no effect on other parts. If they all wrote to the same file, then it is much harder recover a single task for failures.

The `part-XXXXX` files are usually not a problem if you are going to consume it again in Spark / Hadoop-based frameworks because since they all use HDFS API, if you ask them to read "foo", they will all read all the `part-XXXXX` files inside foo as well.

Comment: Thank you, that's is very nice explanation and answers my question completely.

Comment: You can then use the hdfs merge command to wrap these into one file: `hdfs dfs -getmerge <src-directory> <dst-file>`

Comment: If the resulting data is small and a single output file would be convenient you can always repartition your data into a single output file with `repartition(1)`. That should only be done with small data, e.g., when you want to hand over a CSV to an analyst to look at in Excel.

Comment: You can also check `coalesce(1)`

Comment: The answer @MFARID  saves a shuffle step.

Answer (score 10):

I'll suggest to do it in this way (Java example):

```
theRddToPrint.coalesce(1, true).saveAsTextFile(textFileName);
FileSystem fs = anyUtilClass.getHadoopFileSystem(rootFolder);
FileUtil.copyMerge(
    fs, new Path(textFileName),
    fs, new Path(textFileNameDestiny),
    true, fs.getConf(), null);
```

Comment: Good answer including the required details.

Answer (score 2):

#### Extending [Tathagata Das](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1632799/tathagata-das) answer to Spark 2.x and Scala 2.11

Using Spark SQL we can do this in one liner

```
//implicits for magic functions like .toDf
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("first", 2.0),
  ("choose", 7.0),
  ("test", 1.5)
).toDF("name", "vals")

//write DataFrame/DataSet to external storage
df.write
  .format("csv")
  .save("csv/file/location")
```

#### Then you can go head and proceed with [adoalonso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27441745/1031945)'s answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea, but not ready code snippet. Internally (as name suggest) Spark uses Hadoop output format. (as well as `InputFormat` when reading from HDFS).

In the hadoop's `FileOutputFormat`  there is protected member `setOutputFormat`, which you can call from the inherited class to set other base name.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a clean solution, but inside a `foreachRDD`() you can basically do whatever you like, also create a new file.

In my solution this is what I do: I save the output on HDFS (for fault tolerance reasons), and inside a `foreachRDD` I also create a TSV file with statistics in a local folder.

I think you could probably do the same if that's what you need.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations