# Write single CSV file using spark-csv

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, spark-csv

I am using https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv , I am trying to write a single CSV, but not able to, it is making a folder.

Need a Scala function which will take parameter like path and file name and write that CSV file.

Answer (score 226):

It is creating a folder with multiple files, because each partition is saved individually. If you need a single output file (still in a folder) you can `repartition` (preferred if upstream data is large, but requires a shuffle):

```
df
   .repartition(1)
   .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
   .option("header", "true")
   .save("mydata.csv")
```

or `coalesce`:

```
df
   .coalesce(1)
   .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
   .option("header", "true")
   .save("mydata.csv")
```

data frame before saving:

All data will be written to `mydata.csv/part-00000`. Before you use this option **be sure you understand what is going on and what is the cost of transferring all data to a single worker**. If you use distributed file system with replication, data will be transfered multiple times - first fetched to a single worker and subsequently distributed over storage nodes.

Alternatively you can leave your code as it is and use general purpose tools like `cat` or [HDFS `getmerge`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#getmerge) to simply merge all the parts afterwards.

Comment: you can use coalesce also : df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
   .option("header", "true")
   .save("mydata.csv")

Comment: spark 1.6 throws an error when we set `.coalesce(1)` it says some FileNotFoundException on _temporary directory. It is still a bug in spark : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2984

Comment: @Harsha Unlikely. Rather a simple result of `coalesce(1)` being highly expensive and usually not practical.

Comment: Agreed @zero323, but if you have a special requirement to consolidate into one file, it should still be possible given that you have ample resources and time.

Comment: @Harsha I don't say there isn't. If you correctly tune GC it should work just fine but it is simply a waste of time and most likely will hurt overall performance. So personally I don't see any reason to bother especially since it is trivially simple to merge files outside Spark without worrying about memory usage at all.

Comment: @zero323 I am new to data bricks and trying to save my result in CSV file and its working well. Can we rename this CSV file while saving it like now filename starts like this "part_0000" and I want to save it as "sample.csv". What should I do for that?

Comment: Well, I got my solution by simply using the move command dbutils.fs.mv(source, destination)

Comment: `coalesce(1)` is more effective, than `repartition(1)` https://stackoverflow.com/a/40983145/1006855

Answer (score 40):

If you are running Spark with HDFS, I've been solving the problem by writing csv files normally and leveraging HDFS to do the merging. I'm doing that in Spark (1.6) directly:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

def merge(srcPath: String, dstPath: String): Unit =  {
   val hadoopConfig = new Configuration()
   val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfig)
   FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(srcPath), hdfs, new Path(dstPath), true, hadoopConfig, null) 
   // the "true" setting deletes the source files once they are merged into the new output
}


val newData = << create your dataframe >>


val outputfile = "/user/feeds/project/outputs/subject"  
var filename = "myinsights"
var outputFileName = outputfile + "/temp_" + filename 
var mergedFileName = outputfile + "/merged_" + filename
var mergeFindGlob  = outputFileName

    newData.write
        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("header", "false")
        .mode("overwrite")
        .save(outputFileName)
    merge(mergeFindGlob, mergedFileName )
    newData.unpersist()
```

Can't remember where I learned this trick, but it might work for you.

Comment: I've not tried it - and suspect it may not be straight forward.

Comment: Thanks. I've [added an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45360343/1048186) that works on Databricks

Comment: @Minkymorgan i have similar problem but not able to do it correctly ..Can you please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46812388/how-to-merge-all-part-files-in-a-folder-created-by-spark-data-frame-and-rename-a

Comment: @SUDARSHAN My function above works with uncompressed data. In your example I think you are using gzip compression as you write files - and then after - trying to merge these together which fails. That isn't going to work, as you can't merge gzip files together. Gzip is not a Splittable Compression algorithm, so certainly not "mergable". You might test "snappy" or "bz2" compression - but gut feel is this will fail too on merge. Probably best best is to remove compression, merge raw files, then compress using a splittable codec.

Comment: and what if I want to preserve header? it duplicates for each file part

Comment: I have seen in more recent spark versions that the databricks utilities can address this issue.  Parquet is a great option if available for you.

Comment: Don't know if this is still alive but can someone tell me why is this metod returning an exception caught: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CSV data source does not support null data type. ?

Comment: It looks like copyMerge was removed in API 3.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12967

Answer (score 39):

I might be a little late to the game here, but using `coalesce(1)` or `repartition(1)` may work for small data-sets, but large data-sets would all be thrown into one partition on one node. This is likely to throw OOM errors, or at best, to process slowly.

I would highly suggest that you use the [`FileUtil.copyMerge()`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html#copyMerge(org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,%20java.lang.String)) function from the Hadoop API. This will merge the outputs into a single file.

**EDIT** - This effectively brings the data to the driver rather than an executor node. `Coalesce()` would be fine if a single executor has more RAM for use than the driver.

**EDIT 2**: `copyMerge()` is being removed in Hadoop 3.0. See the following stack overflow article for more information on how to work with the newest version: [How to do CopyMerge in Hadoop 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035735/hadoop-how-to-do-copymerge-in-hadoop-3-0)

Comment: Any thoughts on how to get a csv with a header row this way?  Wouldn't want to have the file produce a header, since that would intersperse headers throughout the file, one for each partition.

Comment: There's an option that I've used in the past documented here: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/11/30/spark-write-to-csv-file-with-header-using-saveasfile/

Answer (score 21):

If you are using Databricks and can fit all the data into RAM on one worker (and thus can use `.coalesce(1)`), you can use dbfs to find and move the resulting CSV file:

```
val fileprefix= "/mnt/aws/path/file-prefix"

dataset
  .coalesce(1)       
  .write             
//.mode("overwrite") // I usually don't use this, but you may want to.
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("delimiter","\t")
  .csv(fileprefix+".tmp")

val partition_path = dbutils.fs.ls(fileprefix+".tmp/")
     .filter(file=>file.name.endsWith(".csv"))(0).path

dbutils.fs.cp(partition_path,fileprefix+".tab")

dbutils.fs.rm(fileprefix+".tmp",recurse=true)
```

If your file does not fit into RAM on the worker, you may want to consider  [chaotic3quilibrium's suggestion to use FileUtils.copyMerge()](https://forums.databricks.com/answers/11316/view.html). I have not done this, and don't yet know if is possible or not, e.g., on S3.

This answer is built on previous answers to this question as well as my own tests of the provided code snippet. [I originally posted it to Databricks](https://forums.databricks.com/answers/12091/view.html) and am republishing it here.

The best documentation for dbfs's rm's recursive option I have found is on [a Databricks forum](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/9663/how-to-delete-a-folder-in-databricks-mnt.html).

Answer (score 16):

spark's `df.write()` API will create multiple part files inside given path ... to force spark write only a single part file use `df.coalesce(1).write.csv(...)` instead of `df.repartition(1).write.csv(...)` as coalesce is a narrow transformation whereas repartition is a wide transformation see [Spark - repartition() vs coalesce()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31612810/5883310)

```
df.coalesce(1).write.csv(filepath,header=True)
```

will create folder in given filepath with one `part-0001-...-c000.csv` file 
use

```
cat filepath/part-0001-...-c000.csv > filename_you_want.csv
```

to have a user friendly filename

Comment: alternatively if the dataframe is not too big (~GBs or can fit in driver memory) you can also use
`df.toPandas().to_csv(path)` this will write single csv with your preferred filename

Answer (score 12):

This answer expands on the accepted answer, gives more context, and provides code snippets you can run in the Spark Shell on your machine.

**More context on accepted answer**

The accepted answer might give you the impression the sample code outputs a single `mydata.csv` file and that's not the case.  Let's demonstrate:

```scala
val df = Seq("one", "two", "three").toDF("num")
df
  .repartition(1)
  .write.csv(sys.env("HOME")+ "/Documents/tmp/mydata.csv")
```

Here's what's outputted:

```
Documents/
  tmp/
    mydata.csv/
      _SUCCESS
      part-00000-b3700504-e58b-4552-880b-e7b52c60157e-c000.csv
```

N.B. `mydata.csv` is a folder in the accepted answer - it's not a file!

**How to output a single file with a specific name**

We can use [spark-daria](https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-daria) to write out a single `mydata.csv` file.

```scala
import com.github.mrpowers.spark.daria.sql.DariaWriters
DariaWriters.writeSingleFile(
    df = df,
    format = "csv",
    sc = spark.sparkContext,
    tmpFolder = sys.env("HOME") + "/Documents/better/staging",
    filename = sys.env("HOME") + "/Documents/better/mydata.csv"
)
```

This'll output the file as follows:

```
Documents/
  better/
    mydata.csv
```

**S3 paths**

You'll need to pass s3a paths to `DariaWriters.writeSingleFile` to use this method in S3:

```scala
DariaWriters.writeSingleFile(
    df = df,
    format = "csv",
    sc = spark.sparkContext,
    tmpFolder = "s3a://bucket/data/src",
    filename = "s3a://bucket/data/dest/my_cool_file.csv"
)
```

See [here](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/output-one-file-csv-parquet/) for more info.

**Avoiding copyMerge**

copyMerge was removed from Hadoop 3.  The `DariaWriters.writeSingleFile` implementation uses `fs.rename`, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48223470/1125159).  [Spark 3 still used Hadoop 2](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Use-Hadoop-3-2-as-a-default-Hadoop-profile-in-3-0-0-td28198.html#a28242), so copyMerge implementations will work in 2020.  I'm not sure when Spark will upgrade to Hadoop 3, but better to avoid any copyMerge approach that'll cause your code to break when Spark upgrades Hadoop.

**Source code**

Look for the `DariaWriters` object in the spark-daria source code if you'd like to inspect the implementation.

**PySpark implementation**

It's easier to write out a single file with PySpark because you can convert the DataFrame to a Pandas DataFrame that gets written out as a single file by default.

```py
from pathlib import Path
home = str(Path.home())
data = [
    ("jellyfish", "JALYF"),
    ("li", "L"),
    ("luisa", "LAS"),
    (None, None)
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["word", "expected"])
df.toPandas().to_csv(home + "/Documents/tmp/mydata-from-pyspark.csv", sep=',', header=True, index=False)
```

**Limitations**

The `DariaWriters.writeSingleFile` Scala approach and the `df.toPandas()` Python approach only work for small datasets.  Huge datasets can not be written out as single files.  Writing out data as a single file isn't optimal from a performance perspective because the data can't be written in parallel.

Comment: Hi, Is the `1.0.0` version of `spark-daria` published to maven repo? I don't see it available there.

Comment: @BandiKishore - Yes, here is the link: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/mrpowers/spark-daria_2.12/1.0.0/

Answer (score 9):

I'm using this in Python to get a single file:

```
df.toPandas().to_csv("/tmp/my.csv", sep=',', header=True, index=False)
```

Comment: This might work but it is not memory efficient method since the driver has to convert the Spark Dataframe to pandas. So it might be a good way if the data not too large.

Comment: With smaller data it works like a charm :-D and your files are not in a weird format :D

Answer (score 5):

A solution that works for S3 modified from Minkymorgan.

Simply pass the temporary partitioned directory path (with different name than final path) as the `srcPath` and single final csv/txt as `destPath`  Specify also `deleteSource` if you want to remove the original directory.

```
/**
* Merges multiple partitions of spark text file output into single file. 
* @param srcPath source directory of partitioned files
* @param dstPath output path of individual path
* @param deleteSource whether or not to delete source directory after merging
* @param spark sparkSession
*/
def mergeTextFiles(srcPath: String, dstPath: String, deleteSource: Boolean): Unit =  {
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil
  import java.net.URI
  val config = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
  val fs: FileSystem = FileSystem.get(new URI(srcPath), config)
  FileUtil.copyMerge(
    fs, new Path(srcPath), fs, new Path(dstPath), deleteSource, config, null
  )
}
```

Comment: copyMerge implementation lists all the files and iterates over them, this is not safe in s3. if you write your files and then list them - this doesn't guarantee that all of them will be listed. see [this|https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel]

Comment: @LiranBo, sorry why exactly does this not guarantee it will work. To quote the linked doc "A process writes a new object to Amazon S3 and immediately lists keys within its bucket. The new object will appear in the list."

Comment: it is now, before Dec 1 2020, s3 didn't guarantee list after write consistency. it does now - [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-strong-read-after-write-consistency/#:~:text=S3%20is%20Now%20Strongly%20Consistent&text=Effective%20immediately%2C%20all%20S3%20GET,metadata%2C%20are%20now%20strongly%20consistent.)

Answer (score 4):

```
spark.sql("select * from df").coalesce(1).write.option("mode","append").option("header","true").csv("/your/hdfs/path/")
```

`spark.sql("select * from df")` --> this is dataframe

`coalesce(1)` or `repartition(1)` --> this will make your output file to 1 part file only

`write` --> writing data

`option("mode","append")` --> appending data to existing directory

`option("header","true")` --> enabling header

`csv("<hdfs dir>")` --> write as CSV file & its output location in HDFS

Comment: You can also use `df.select("*")`, but if using HDFS, almost all Hadoop tools accept a directory of files, so it is better to let Spark split the file for future parallel file-reads

Answer (score 3):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame,SaveMode,SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

I solved using below approach (hdfs rename file name):-

Step 1:- (Crate Data Frame and write to HDFS)

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("header", "false").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save("/hdfsfolder/blah/")
```

Step 2:- (Create Hadoop Config)

```
val hadoopConfig = new Configuration()
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfig)
```

Step3 :- (Get path in hdfs folder path)

```
val pathFiles = new Path("/hdfsfolder/blah/")
```

Step4:- (Get spark file names from hdfs folder)

```
val fileNames = hdfs.listFiles(pathFiles, false)
println(fileNames)
```

setp5:- (create scala mutable list to save all the file names and add it to the list)

```
    var fileNamesList = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[String]()
    while (fileNames.hasNext) {
      fileNamesList += fileNames.next().getPath.getName
    }
    println(fileNamesList)
```

Step 6:- (filter _SUCESS file order from file names scala list)

```
    // get files name which are not _SUCCESS
    val partFileName = fileNamesList.filterNot(filenames => filenames == "_SUCCESS")
```

step 7:- (convert scala list to string and add desired file name to hdfs folder string and then apply rename)

```
val partFileSourcePath = new Path("/yourhdfsfolder/"+ partFileName.mkString(""))
    val desiredCsvTargetPath = new Path(/yourhdfsfolder/+ "op_"+ ".csv")
    hdfs.rename(partFileSourcePath , desiredCsvTargetPath)
```

Answer (score 2):

repartition/coalesce to 1 partition before you save (you'd still get a folder but it would have one part file in it)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `rdd.coalesce(1, true).saveAsTextFile(path)`

it will store data as singile file in path/part-00000

Answer (score 1):

Here is a helper function with which you can get a single result-file without the `part-0000` and without a subdirectory on S3 and AWS EMR:

```scala
def renameSinglePartToParentFolder(directoryUrl: String): Unit = {
    import sys.process._
    val lsResult = s"aws s3 ls ${directoryUrl}/" !!
    val partFilename = lsResult.split("\n").map(_.split(" ").last).filter(_.contains("part-0000")).last
    
    s"aws s3 rm ${directoryUrl}/_SUCCESS" !
    
    s"aws s3 mv ${directoryUrl}/${partFilename} ${directoryUrl}" !
}

val targetPath = "s3://my-bucket/my-folder/my-file.csv"
df.coalesce(1).write.csv(targetPath)
renameSinglePartToParentFolder(targetPath)
```

1. Write to a single `part-0000...` file.
2. Use AWS CLI to list all files and rename the single file accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

by using Listbuffer we can save data into single file:

```
import java.io.FileWriter
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
    val text = spark.read.textFile("filepath")
    var data = ListBuffer[String]()
    for(line:String <- text.collect()){
      data += line
    }
    val writer = new FileWriter("filepath")
    data.foreach(line => writer.write(line.toString+"\n"))
    writer.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def export_csv(  
  fileName: String,
  filePath: String
  ) = {

  val filePathDestTemp = filePath + ".dir/"
  val merstageout_df = spark.sql(merstageout)

  merstageout_df
    .coalesce(1)
    .write
    .option("header", "true")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .csv(filePathDestTemp)
  
  val listFiles = dbutils.fs.ls(filePathDestTemp)

  for(subFiles <- listFiles){
      val subFiles_name: String = subFiles.name
      if (subFiles_name.slice(subFiles_name.length() - 4,subFiles_name.length()) == ".csv") {
        dbutils.fs.cp (filePathDestTemp + subFiles_name,  filePath + fileName+ ".csv")
        dbutils.fs.rm(filePathDestTemp, recurse=true)
      }}}
```

Answer (score -2):

There is one more way to use Java

```
import java.io._

def printToFile(f: java.io.File)(op: java.io.PrintWriter => Unit) 
  {
     val p = new java.io.PrintWriter(f);  
     try { op(p) } 
     finally { p.close() }
  } 

printToFile(new File("C:/TEMP/df.csv")) { p => df.collect().foreach(p.println)}
```

Comment: name 'true' is not defined

Comment: I wouldn't call using `.collect()` as a "solution"