# How to export DataFrame to csv in Scala?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

How can I export Spark's DataFrame to csv file using Scala?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Easiest and best way to do this is to use [`spark-csv`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) library. You can check the documentation in the provided link and [`here`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#scala-api) is the scala example of how to load and save data from/to DataFrame.

**Code (Spark 1.4+):**

```
dataFrame.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("myFile.csv")
```

**Edit:**

Spark creates part-files while saving the csv data, if you want to merge the part-files into a single csv, refer the following:

[Merge Spark's CSV output folder to Single File](http://deploymentzone.com/2015/01/30/spark-and-merged-csv-files/)

Answer (score 15):

In **Spark verions 2+** you can simply use the following;

```
df.write.csv("/your/location/data.csv")
```

If you want to make sure that the files are no longer partitioned then add a `.coalesce(1)` as follows;

```
df.coalesce(1).write.csv("/your/location/data.csv")
```

Comment: Can we rename the part_0000 file?

Comment: You can easily rename it after it's written out if you wish by using `cp <old filepath> <new filepath>` (or `hdfs dfs -cp <old filepath> <new filepath>` if the file is still in hdfs) to copy the file to its current location but with the new name

Comment: Please note this doesn't export with headers

Answer (score 13):

Above solution exports csv as multiple partitions. I found another solution by [zero323](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1560062/zero323) on this [stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674530/write-single-csv-file-using-spark-csv) that exports a dataframe into one single CSV file when you use `coalesce`.

```
df.coalesce(1)
  .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .save("/your/location/mydata")
```

This would create a directory named `mydata` where you'll find a `csv` file that contains the results.

Answer (score 0):

A method to export and rename the file:

```
def export_csv(  
  fileName: String,
  filePath: String
  ) = {

  val filePathDestTemp = filePath + ".dir/"
  val merstageout_df = spark.sql(merstageout)

  merstageout_df
    .coalesce(1)
    .write
    .option("header", "true")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .csv(filePathDestTemp)
  
  val listFiles = dbutils.fs.ls(filePathDestTemp)

  for(subFiles <- listFiles){
      val subFiles_name: String = subFiles.name
      if (subFiles_name.slice(subFiles_name.length() - 4,subFiles_name.length()) == ".csv") {
        dbutils.fs.cp (filePathDestTemp + subFiles_name,  filePath + fileName+ ".csv")
        dbutils.fs.rm(filePathDestTemp, recurse=true)
      }}}
```