# error: overloaded method value options with alternatives

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to save my dataFrame in s3 like below:

```
myDF.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(codec="org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec").save("s3n://myPath/myData.csv")
```

Then I got errors:

```
<console>:132: error: overloaded method value options with alternatives:
  (options: java.util.Map[String,String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter <and>
  (options: scala.collection.Map[String,String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter
 cannot be applied to (codec: String)
```

Does anyone know what I missed? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Scala is not Python. It doesn't have **kwargs. You have to provide `Map`:

```
myDF.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .options(Map("codec" -> "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec"))
  .save("s3n://myPath/myData.csv")
```

Comment: Instead of saving to one myData.csv file, I actually got a myData.csv "folder", where multiple csv.gz files are stored under the folder. Is there a way just to save it to a csv file. Thanks!

Comment: @Edamame You cannot have a single file [without coalescing to a single partition](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31675351/1560062) and this is basically useless unless size of the output is negligible.

Comment: @zero323: Thanks! assuming I coalescing to a single partition, how do I save it to one csv file? Thanks!

Comment: use repartition as mentioned in zero323's comment