# About the dataframe, how to add header to output csv file

Tags: apache-spark

I have a dataframe like below:

```
+---+-----+-------------------+
|  x|    y|                  z|
+---+-----+-------------------+
|xyz|12223|A,123@B,456@C,98765|
|abc|12456|              A,123|
+---+-----+-------------------+
```

I save it as csv:

```
index.write.csv("D:\\spark\\tmp\\dd2")
```

two issues here:

1. Would you like tell me how to save the column name x,y,z to the header of csv 
   please?
2. How can I save the output to a single file please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would you like tell me how to save the column name x,y,z to the header of csv please?

You have to use `header` option:

```
index.write.option("header", "true").write(path)
```

> How can I save the output to a single file please?

[Write single CSV file using spark-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31674530/8371915)

Comment: @Robin Where are you defining header name like x,y,z?