# How to coalesce large portioned data into single directory in spark/Hive

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe, hive

I have a requirement, 
Huge data is partitioned and inserting it into Hive.To bind this data, I am using `DF.Coalesce(10)`. Now i want to bind this portioned data to single directory, if I use `DF.Coalesce(1)` will the performance decrease? or do I have any other process to do so?

Comment: If you have "huge" data, putting everything in one partition is not recommended. You might end up overwhelmed your master node and thus it will fail...

Comment: @eliasah: can you please suggest how i suppose to handle this scenario

Comment: I strongly suggest to read this question and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674530/write-single-csv-file-using-spark-csv

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand is that you are trying to ensure that there are less no of files per partition. So, by using `coalesce(10)`, you will get max 10 files per partition. I would suggest using `repartition($"COL")`, here COL is the column used to partition the data. This will ensure that your "huge" data is split based on the partition column used in HIVE. `df.repartition($"COL")`

Comment: I guess `df.repartition($"COL")` wont help in my case... because i want data in a single directory...

Comment: If you are writing to the same directory you will need to just use `df.repartition(100)` to get 100 equal size files. because you are not partitioned, no need to use column to distribute the data.