# Write DataFrame from Databricks to Data Lake

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, databricks

It happens that I am manipulating some data using Azure Databricks. Such data is in an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1. I mounted the data into DBFS, but now, after transforming the data I would like to write it back into my data lake.

To mount the data I used the following:

```
configs = {"dfs.adls.oauth2.access.token.provider.type": "ClientCredential",
       "dfs.adls.oauth2.client.id": "<your-service-client-id>",
       "dfs.adls.oauth2.credential": "<your-service-credentials>",
       "dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your-directory-id>/oauth2/token"}

dbutils.fs.mount(source = "adl://<your-data-lake-store-account-name>.azuredatalakestore.net/<your-directory-name>", mount_point = "/mnt/<mount-name>",extra_configs = configs)
```

I want to write back a .csv file.  For this task I am using the following line

```
dfGPS.write.mode("overwrite").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").csv("adl://<your-data-lake-store-account-name>.azuredatalakestore.net/<your-directory-name>")
```

However, I get the following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: u'No value for dfs.adls.oauth2.access.token.provider found in conf file.'
```

Any piece of code that can help me? Or link that walks me through.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you mount Azure Data Lake Store, you should use the mountpoint to store your data, instead of "adl://...". For details how to mount Azure Data Lake Store 
 (ADLS ) Gen1 see the [Azure Databricks documentation](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake.html#azure-data-lake-storage-gen1). You can verify if the mountpoint works with:

```
dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/<newmountpoint>")
```

So try after mounting ADLS Gen 1:

```
dfGPS.write.mode("overwrite").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").csv("mnt/<mount-name>/<your-directory-name>")
```

This should work if you added the mountpoint properly and you have also the access rights with the Service Principal on the ADLS.

Spark writes always multiple files in a directory, because each partition is saved individually. See also the following [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674530/write-single-csv-file-using-spark-csv).

Comment: Mr. Mallow, can you suggest me some link where I can find good practices to work with Azure Databricks and Data Lake Storage Gen1? Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer, pls check the doc and also if you have sufficient rights to access ADLS with the Service Principal.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. Any suggestion about "good practices"?

Comment: I have another question regarding this. When I write the file back to data lake, A pseudorandom name is assigned, how can I choose the name that I want for such .csv file?

Comment: That' s normal spark behaviour, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674530/write-single-csv-file-using-spark-csv .

Comment: Hi, is it possible to write data to ADLS Tables also this way?

Comment: Are you referring to Spark tables? Yes this will work.