# In R and Sparklyr, writing a table to .CSV (spark_write_csv) yields many files, not one single file. Why? And can I change that?

Tags: r, csv, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

**Background**

I'm doing some data manipulation (joins, etc.) on a very large dataset in `R`, so I decided to use a local installation of Apache Spark and `sparklyr` to be able to use my `dplyr` code to manipulate it all. (I'm running Windows 10 Pro; `R` is 64-bit.) I've done the work needed, and now want to output the `sparklyr` table to a .csv file.

**The Problem**

Here's the code I'm using to output a .csv file to a folder on my hard drive:

```
spark_write_csv(d1, "C:/d1.csv")
```

When I navigate to the directory in question, though, I don't see a single csv file `d1.csv`. Instead I see a newly created folder called `d1`, and when I click inside it I see ~10 .csv files all beginning with "part". Here's a screenshot:

[image]

The folder also contains the same number of `.csv.crc` files, which I see from Googling are "used to store CRC code for a split file archive".

What's going on here? Is there a way to put these files back together, or to get `spark_write_csv` to output a single file like `write.csv`?

**Edit**

A user below suggested that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674530/write-single-csv-file-using-spark-csv) may answer the question, and it nearly does, but it seems like the asker is looking for Scala code that does what I want, while I'm looking for `R` code that does what I want.

Comment: Repartition the data ---> [Write single CSV file using spark-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674530/write-single-csv-file-using-spark-csv)

Comment: Apologies for not seeing that post -- my searches of relevant prior posts all included the [r] and [sparklyr] tags. Good looking out, sir (or ma'am).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data will be divided into multiple partitions. When you save the dataframe to CSV, you will get file from each partition. Before calling spark_write_csv method you need to bring all the data to single partition to get single file.

You can use a method called as [coalese](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/coalesce.html) to achieve this.

```
coalesce(df, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, Mohana. I'm going to try this out when I get back to the office. I'll report back if I encounter any trouble but this looks like it'll work.

Comment: When I run `coalesce(d1, 1)`, I get this error: `Error: '..1' must be a vector, not a <tbl_spark/tbl_sql/tbl_lazy/tbl> object.` Did I miss something?

Comment: EDIT: `R` was thinking I wanted `dplyr::coalesce`, when you're referring to a `coalesce` function that's inside Spark. I see. `R`'s spark frontend, `sparklyr`, apparently uses `sdf_coalesce` on the `R` side to call `coalesce` inside Spark.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue.

In simple terms, the partitions are done for computational efficiency. If you have partitions, multiple workers/executors can write the table on each partition. In contrast, if you only have one partition, the csv file can only be written by a single worker/executor, making the task much slower. The same principle applies not only for writing tables but also for parallel computations.

For more details on partitioning, you can check [this link](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-partitioning-understanding/).

Suppose I want to save `table` as a single file with the path `path/to/table.csv`. I would do this as follows

```
table %>% sdf_repartition(partitions=1)
spark_write_csv(table, path/to/table.csv,...)
```

You can check full details of `sdf_repartition` in the [official documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/sparklyr/man/sdf_repartition.html).