# How to get the input from local and store it to local in a dataframe

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{min, max, avg}
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
    
    val data = spark.read.option("header","true").format("csv").load("cpid_data.csv")
    
   val equi = data.withColumn("value",col("value").cast("double")).groupBy("id").agg(avg("value"), max("value"), min("value")).show()
```

In the above code when I try to write the output in a csv file like,

```
equi.write.option("header",true).csv("cpido.csv")
```

It is throwing error like write is not a member of unit.

could anyone help me with this? How to load the output to a csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is giving you a strong indication: *`write` is not a member of `Unit`* means there's no method called `write` on the type `Unit`.

Said differently: `equi` is of type `Unit`, which is probably not what you desired.

Just remove the call to `.show()` and it'll work fine:

```scala
val equi = data
  .withColumn("value",col("value").cast("double"))
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(avg("value"), max("value"), min("value"))

equi.write.option("header",true).csv("cpido.csv")
```

Comment: That works but the output is displayed as individual csv file for each row in the output. why is that?

Comment: @Vikram see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674530/write-single-csv-file-using-spark-csv

Comment: repartition and coalesce is not working in my case. Do we need to import anything in terms of scala code?