# How to write the resulting RDD to a csv file in Spark python

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, file-writing

I have a resulting RDD `labelsAndPredictions = testData.map(lambda lp: lp.label).zip(predictions)`. This has output in this format:

```
[(0.0, 0.08482142857142858), (0.0, 0.11442786069651742),.....]
```

What I want is to create a CSV file with one column for `labels` (the first part of the tuple in above output) and one for `predictions`(second part of tuple output). But I don't know how to write to a CSV file in Spark using Python.

How can I create a CSV file with the above output?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just `map` the lines of the RDD (`labelsAndPredictions`) into strings (the lines of the CSV) then use `rdd.saveAsTextFile()`.

```
def toCSVLine(data):
  return ','.join(str(d) for d in data)

lines = labelsAndPredictions.map(toCSVLine)
lines.saveAsTextFile('hdfs://my-node:9000/tmp/labels-and-predictions.csv')
```

Comment: Just as a doubt, so where will this save the `csv` file? In the same directory as where the code is present?Can I save it to other directory (using `saveAsTextFile('/home/files/labels-and-predictions.csv')` )?

Comment: You can use any path the Hadoop client library understands. Typically it will be a path on a distributed file system. I've updated the example to illustrate this. But if you're just testing on one machine, you can use a local path as well.

Comment: I tried to use it but when I execute it creates a directory named 'labels-and-predictions.csv' and inside that directory there are two files - _SUCCESS and part-00000

Comment: Yeah, that's the output. It will be split into multiple files if the RDD is made up of multiple partitions. Is this a problem for you? This is perfectly normal and desired in big data use cases.

Comment: so to read this csv file again somewhere else in ipython I just need to put the 'labels-and-predictions.csv' and all the part files inside that will be read automatically?

Comment: It depends on the tool. Hadoop tools will read all the `part-xxx` files. Spark will also read it when you use `sc.textFile`. For conventional tools you may need to merge the data into a single file first. If the output is small enough to be handled by conventional tools though, there is no reason to save it via Spark. Just `collect` the RDD and write the data to a local file without Spark.

Comment: It doesn't seem standard to assume that a .csv extension in the destination path guarantees that csv will be written, as illustrated in the 5th comment above. It seems more common that protocols involved with hdfs and s3 may encrypt and compress the output resulting in a non-csv file.

Answer (score 24):

I know this is an old post. But to help someone searching for the same, here's how I write a two column RDD to a single CSV file in PySpark 1.6.2

The RDD:

```
>>> rdd.take(5)
[(73342, u'cells'), (62861, u'cell'), (61714, u'studies'), (61377, u'aim'), (60168, u'clinical')]
```

Now the code:

```
# First I convert the RDD to dataframe
from pyspark import SparkContext
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ['count', 'word'])
```

The DF:

```
>>> df.show()
+-----+-----------+
|count|       word|
+-----+-----------+
|73342|      cells|
|62861|       cell|
|61714|    studies|
|61377|        aim|
|60168|   clinical|
|59275|          2|
|59221|          1|
|58274|       data|
|58087|development|
|56579|     cancer|
|50243|    disease|
|49817|   provided|
|49216|   specific|
|48857|     health|
|48536|      study|
|47827|    project|
|45573|description|
|45455|  applicant|
|44739|    program|
|44522|   patients|
+-----+-----------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Now write to CSV

```
# Write CSV (I have HDFS storage)
df.coalesce(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').save('file:///home/username/csv_out')
```

P.S: I am just a beginner learning from posts here in Stackoverflow. So I don't know whether this is the best way. But it worked for me and I hope it will help someone!

Comment: I had to encode some columns w/ JSON but otherwise this works

Comment: @lnsiloco, how to write this to a Snowflake or a Redshift database? Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

It's not good to just join by commas because if fields contain commas, they won't be properly quoted, e.g. `','.join(['a', 'b', '1,2,3', 'c'])` gives you `a,b,1,2,3,c` when you'd want `a,b,"1,2,3",c`. Instead, you should use Python's csv module to convert each list in the RDD to a properly-formatted csv string:

```py
# python 3
import csv, io

def list_to_csv_str(x):
    """Given a list of strings, returns a properly-csv-formatted string."""
    output = io.StringIO("")
    csv.writer(output).writerow(x)
    return output.getvalue().strip() # remove extra newline

# ... do stuff with your rdd ...
rdd = rdd.map(list_to_csv_str)
rdd.saveAsTextFile("output_directory")
```

Since the csv module only writes to file objects, we have to create an empty "file" with `io.StringIO("")` and tell the csv.writer to write the csv-formatted string into it. Then, we use `output.getvalue()` to get the string we just wrote to the "file". To make this code work with Python 2, just replace io with the StringIO module.

If you're using the Spark DataFrames API, you can also look into the [DataBricks save function](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#python-api), which has a csv format.

Comment: I get a TypeError using this code. TypeError: can't write str to text stream.

Comment: @Moe Chughtai Which version of Spark/Python are you using? Which line gives you the type error, and on what input?

Answer (score -2):

```
    def toCSV(RDD):

        for element in RDD:
        return ','.join(str(element))

    rows_of_csv=RDD.map(toCSV)
    rows_of_csv.saveAsTextFile('/FileStore/tables/name_of_csv_file.csv')

# choose your path based on your distributed file system
```