# Writing pyspark Rdd into csv file

Tags: pyspark

How can I write my pyspark RDD's contents into a csv file. I am using the below code but it is not working :

```
df.saveAsTextFile(r'D:\asdf.csv')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write the resulting RDD to a csv file in Spark python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31898964/how-to-write-the-resulting-rdd-to-a-csv-file-in-spark-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the spark-csv package from Databricks: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

```
df.save('df.csv', 'com.databricks.spark.csv')
```