# Write RDD to csv with split columns

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

I am just getting started with Pyspark and would like to save a file as a csv instead of a text file. I tried using a couple of answers I found on Stack Overflow such as

```
def toCSVLine(data):
   return ','.join(str(d) for d in data)
```

and then

```
 rdd = lines.map(toCSVLine)
 rdd.saveAsTextFile("file.csv")
```

It works in that I can open it in excel, however all the information is put into column A in the spreadsheet. I would like to be able to put each column in the rdd (an example would be ("ID", "rating") into a separate column in excel so ID would be in column A and rating would be in column B. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to convert RDD to dataframe and then save as CSV.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ['count', 'word'])
# Write CSV (I have HDFS storage)
df.coalesce(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').save('file:///home/username/csv_out')
```

Please see this post I just made: 
[How to write the resulting RDD to a csv file in Spark python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31898964/how-to-write-the-resulting-rdd-to-a-csv-file-in-spark-python/42378985#42378985)

Comment: This did work, but is there a way to get it to ignore commas inside quotes? It split up a line of text I need to keep together into multiple columns because it has some commas in it.

Comment: You can probably use another delimiter with .option("delimiter", "|") and use that delimiter when opening is Excel

Comment: Alright I was able to get it to work with this code. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The `coalesce(1)` here is problematic though. What if your data does not fit into one partition? I think it's smarter to skip the `coalesce` and concat the resulting files using other tools (e.g. `cat` on the commandline, or your standard python file operations)

Answer (score 1):

In excel are you splitting the file on the ','?

In excel go to the **Data** tab and select **text to columns** under data tools then select **delimited** and hit next. Then select **comma** as the delimiter and hit finish.

**Edit**

Generally it would be best practice to create a csv with a different separator character than comma if commas will be in your data. Per your comment if you are creating the csv, just use a different separator (e.g. ';', '|', '^', or tabs). Another option, which I prefer less, is to wrap the field in question in "" like so:

```
field0,field1,"field,2",field3
```

Excel should leave what is in quotes alone and only split on commas outside of the quotes. But again this is not my preferred solution.

Comment: I did try this method, but it split up one of the columns where there was a line of text with multiple commas in it into multiple columns. Is there a way to use this method while ignoring commas inside quotes?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Spark >= 2.0 and assuming your RDD has a tabular format (which it should, given you want to save it as CSV) one way might be to first create a Dataframe from the RDD and then use [DataFrameWriter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter) to export to CSV.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession(sc).getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataframe(rdd)

df.write.csv("/path/to/file.csv", sep=',', header=True)
```

Have a look at [the pyspark.sql docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame) for additional options and further information.

Comment: Is there a way to use a comma as a delimiter while ignoring commas inside quotes?

Comment: Commas inside strings should be fine, as strings should be automatically quoted. Have you tried the options `sep`, `quote`, `escape` etc?