# Why Spark creates multiple csv files while saving a dataframe in csv format?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to understand how spark determines the number of csv files it creates while saving a data frame as csv file. Does the number of partitions affect this number? and why are some empty files created? I have the code like follows

```
dataframe.coalesce(numPartitions).write
   .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
   .option("delimiter", "|")
   .option("header", "true")
   .mode("overwrite")
   .save("outputpath")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write to CSV in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23527941/how-to-write-to-csv-in-spark)

Comment: Short answer: 1 part file per partition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiples files when you save in `csv` or any other format, Its because of a multiple number of the partition of your dataframe. If you have `n` number of partition then you get `n` number of files saved in output.

> Does the number of partitions affect this number?

Yes, the number of partition is equal to the number of files. While saviong the datarfame/rdd each partition is written as a single file.

> why are some empty files created?

All the partitions may not contain data

Hope this helps!